# Error while executing filter CleanAttributesFilter - TypeError: Object expected

Tags: telerik, radwindow, radeditor

I'm using the Telerik's RadEditor, in a RadWindow, which servers as a Modal Popup in an ASP.net app.
When I tried displaying the Modal Popup.
I get the following error, only in Microsoft Edge Browser:

> "Error while executing filter CleanAttributesFilter - TypeError: Object expected".

It works well in Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer, but it throws an exception in Microsoft Edge.
I've tried to disable the filters by including this, in the code behind.

```
RadEditor1.EnableFilter(EditorFilters.None)
```

That did not fix it. Has anyone experienced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To disable a filter in RadEditor use:

RadEditor1.DisableFilter(EditorFilters.ConvertToXhtml);